# Akka: How to ensure that message has been received?

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, actor

I have an actor Dispenser. What it does is it

1. dispenses some objects by request
2. listens to arriving new ones

Code follows

```
class Dispenser extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case Get =>
            context.sender ! getObj()
        case x: SomeType =>
            addObj(x)
    }
}
```

In real processing it doesn't matter whether 1 ms or even few seconds passed since new object was sent until the dispenser starts to dispense it, so there's no code tracking it.

But now I'm writing test for the dispenser and I want to be sure that firstly it receives new object and only then it receives a Get request.

Here's the test code I came up with:

```
val dispenser = system.actorOf(Props.create(classOf[Dispenser]))
dispenser ! obj
Thread.sleep(100)
val task = dispenser ? Get()
val result = Await.result(task, timeout)
check(result)
```

It satisfies one important requirement - it **doesn't change original code**. But it is

1. At least 100ms seconds slow even on very high performance boxes
2. Unstable and fails sometimes because 100 ms or any other constant doesn't provide any guaranties.

And the question is **how to make a test that satisfies requirement and doesn't have cons above** (neither any other obvious cons)

Comment: You may have to make the test parametric: change the sleep time to 1 millisecond, and run it a whole bunch of times. If it works > 92% of the time, the test passes. 92% is a figure I pulled out of the air. Chose your number and get happy with it.

Comment: I don't think that killing deployment process (that includes automated tests run) in 8% (or even 0.01%) of cases is proper way to make tests. So I would prefer the solution that doesn't involve statistics

Comment: In first version of akka there was a solution based on mailbox size. For akka2 this functionality was disabled. However mailbox still can be implemented in your own. But does there exist an easier and more intuitive solution?

Comment: Have you read http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/message-delivery-reliability.html ?

Comment: @Daenyth Thanks for the link. I'm open to solutions similar to ask pattern, where everything works in case of successful delivery and in other case it waits no more than given timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can take out the `Thread.sleep(..)` and your test will be fine.  Akka guarantees the ordering you need.

With the code

```
dispenser ! obj
val task = dispenser ? Get()
```

`dispenser` will process `obj` before `Get` deterministically because

1. The same thread puts `obj` then `Get` in the actor's mailbox, so they're in the correct order in the actor's mailbox
2. Actors process messages sequentially and one-at-a-time, so the two messages will be received by the actor and processed in the order they're queued in the mailbox.

(..if there's nothing else going on that's not in your sample code - routers, async processing in getObj or addObj, stashing, ..)

Comment: This is not true. The ordering guaranties are applicable only for messages sent in fire and forget manner. When using ask pattern message avoids mailbox and goes directly to destination, so no guaranties about obj and Get() order.

Comment: The request of an `.ask()` is just a `.tell()` - check out [ask() impl in the source](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/AskSupport.scala#L170).

Comment: Firstly, due to [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html): The `ask` operation involves creating an internal actor. And secondly it really occurs (even more, it often does) that the order actually changes.

Comment: The internal actor is to receive the response - the request is via `.tell` in the calling thread.  Did you check out the `AskSupport` source code?

Comment: Your could use tell Obj, tell Get and then expectMsg if you are using akka testkit. That will guarantee message order.

Answer (score 0):

Akka FSM module is really handy for testing underlying state and behavior of the actor and does not require to change its implementation specifically for tests. 
By using TestFSMRef one can get actors current state and and data by:

```
val testActor = TestFSMRef(<actors constructor or Props>)
testActor.stateName shouldBe <state name>
testActor.stateData shouldBe <state data>
```

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/fsm.html